# Xamarin.Forms Back Stack of NavigationPage inside Details view of MasterDetail using PRISM

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

I'm using Xamarin.Forms with PRISM. My app start with navigating to `MyMasterDetailPage/MyNavigationPage/MainPage`. From the master page, I want to navigate to `page2` and have a back arrow instead of the hamburger icon. Pressing that takes you back to MainPage and the hamburger icon is back. I have tried navigating to `MyNavigationPage/page2 and`MyMasterDetailPage/MyNavigationPage/page2` but it seems to be clearing the back stack. There may be other pages that need the behavior that I'm currently seeing, so being able to configure the behavior would be ideal (not always one way or the other).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement the INavigationPageOptions interface on your MyNavigationPage and set the ClearNavigationStackOnNavigation property to false.